# Aligning Brand name and nav buttons on opposite ends

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started learning and using **bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6-dist**.
The problem I am facing is that I cant understand how to place the brand name to the left and the nav items on the right hand side.

I tried this:

```
<body>
    <div class="site-wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar" role="navigation">
            <a class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>
            <a class="navbar-link">
                About
            </a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a basic navigation with left and right aligned links.

```
<body>
   <div class="site-wrapper">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse fixed-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Name</a>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto"></ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-right">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right-aligned Link</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    </div>

<script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I would, however advise that you stick to the [latest stable version](http://getbootstrap.com) of Bootstrap for learning as Version 4 is still in Beta and as such, doesn't provide a lot comprehensive documentation, especially for learning, yet.

Comment: On doing the above, I can only see **Brand Name** and nothing else

Comment: [I have written the code to a pen](http://codepen.io/KevinBonkewitzz/pen/MJQyQR), which is displaying correctly for me, please see if it is the same for you, if so, then there is something else wrong on your code elsewhere.

Comment: ok, The codepen works and locally too. But what I was looking was, I wanted to have only the right-aligned link and not the left aligned

Comment: [I have updated the code](http://codepen.io/KevinBonkewitzz/pen/MJQyQR), let me know if this is closer to what you wanted.

Comment: Perfect! Can you guide me how can I go about learning bootstrap a better way?

Comment: Sure, the best advice I can give is to [stick to the latest stable release of Bootstrap (currently V3.3.7)](http://getbootstrap.com), since there is ample support for it, and cleaner syntax. When a release version of V4 is released, then move onto it. Otherwise, just keep doing what you're doing, the best way to learn is to practice.

Comment: I just shifted to v.3 but then the design broke

Comment: Certain syntax has changed from V3 to V4, refer to the documentation for help. For example, [navigational bars](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav)